# Trying to Disable Secure Boot

Tags: linux, bios, linux-mint, secure-boot

I am trying to disable Secure Boot in my Linux Mint OS. My laptop is an [Acer Aspire 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Aspire_laptops#Aspire_series).

The problem is I can use the arrow keys on all BIOS menus, except *Security* and *Boot*. When I navigate to the *Security* or *Boot* menu, the up and down arrow keys are somehow disabled. When I am exploring the *Main*, *Advanced*, *Power*, and *Exit*, I can use the up and down arrow key.

I am trying to install [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox), and I have encountered this process:
*[VirtualBox installation errors](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=369441)*. I am trying to follow this guide. One of the solutions provided here is to disable secure boot and also I have encountered this:

> The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module available for the current kernel (5.15.0-33-generic) or it failed to load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by '/sbin/vboxconfig'

Now the main problem is in the BIOS menu, specifically, menu *Boot* and *Security*. When trying to select an item, the up and down arrow keys are disabled.

Comment: 1. Why disable Secure Boot? Most recent Linux ditros work with it on. 2. Do you need to create and enter a password in BIOS to disable it?

Comment: 2) No it doesn't ask me for password or anything. I have edited my post thank you!

Comment: In some versions of BIOS, one must **enter**, i.e., **create an initial password**, in order to change some settings. If you do not **set** a password, those options are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's a problem with the `vboxdrv` signature, there are three solutions to your problem:

1. Disable secure boot. Try setting the BIOS password as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103963/287638).
2. Sign the kernel module yourself as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248316/2271495).
3. Install the signed kernel module from your OS repositories as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050071/287638).